# Can I run two virtual Windows Server 2008 machines in an NLB Cluster all on one Windows 7 box?

Tags: windows-server-2008, load-balancing, virtualhost, cluster, nlb

I am writing a prototype ASP.NET web application that demonstrates the use of distributed caching for scalability purposes.  In order to do this, I would like to set up a couple of load balanced windows servers to play around with.  Having only my humble Windows 7 laptop (Win 7 Ultimate 64 bit, Intel Core 2 Duo 2.2 GHz, 4 GB RAM, 300 GB HD), will it be possible to create two virtual Server 2008 boxes configured in an NLB Cluster?  I'm not particularly concerned with performance.  I just need something to play around with on which I can create a couple of proof-of-concept applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, however you should drop some more RAM in the machine first otherwise your host OS won't have much RAM left for it.

Comment: Also I would recommend only installing "server core". It has no GUI thus saving recources.